# Buying dwarf Cavendish banana tree online?

Tags: fruit-trees, containers, banana

Where can I buy a small dwarf Cavendish banana tree online?

I know I can Google it, but I prefer suggestions from people who have bought online before.

I could also buy in amazon, but the reviews were disappointing.

Thanks

Comment: Buying questions are off topic.

Comment: We could probably help you with your decision to purchase this banana tree.  Where is it that you live?  Your zone?  Are you going to grow this banana tree out of doors, in doors or in a green house?  Tell us more, there are very reputable sites to buy great seeds, plants, vegetable starts, trees...but let's go back to the beginning...where will this banana tree live.